# How place special value in string into Array String

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sorting

I have a problem that I can't solve. I need to do something like this:

```
var text = "[{\"VID\":\"115\"},{\"VID\":\"119\"},{\"VID\":\"116\"},...]";
```

I would like to get the following result based on the "text" variable:

```
var VIDs = ["115", "119", "116", ...];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you can use a simple regex to extract all the numerical values

```js
var text = "[{\"VID\":\"115\"},{\"VID\":\"119\"},{\"VID\":\"116\"}]";
var vids = text.match(/\d+/g);

snippet.log(JSON.stringify(vids))
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

---

Another solution using JSON processing is

```js
var text = "[{\"VID\":\"115\"},{\"VID\":\"119\"},{\"VID\":\"116\"}]";
var vids = JSON.parse(text).map(function(obj) {
  return obj.VID;
});

snippet.log(JSON.stringify(vids))
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```